# mount.ntfs takes 90% of CPU

Tags: wubi, mount, ntfs

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Samsung NC10 laptop with 2 GB RAM using WUBI.
When I try to install something or to do something with files, the `mount.ntfs` takes 90% of CPU. Also I have an issue that Ubuntu uses all 2GB of RAM (1GB immediately after start and usage increases).

What can I do with this issue?

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem, just did the same. Apparently even though on the ubuntu website Wubi is quite promoted as "click and play" - it's quite problematic. Some of the problems are due to the ntfs-3g driver which is, well, buggy. They have a commercial version of the driver (you know, $$) which works better. 
To sum up, you'd need to install Ubuntu on a separate drive, with no ntfs partitions on it.

Comment: seems a bit subjective, unsubstantiated, not really an answer to the question as stated.

Comment: This answer was given to me by a whole bunch of Ubuntu experts giving support on the #ubuntu channel in Freenode. And judging by the actual results (I did try both ways) they were very right. Of course you have the right to downvote just bcause you had a bad day:)

Comment: If I had a bad day I wouldn't be on askubuntu.com :) and I hope my -1s are not related to that. Maybe just supply some references for the ntfs-3g bugs and qualify how wubi is problematic, and how this relates to the specific problem... then I'll remove the -1 (otherwise you might as well go to every question tagged `wubi` and answer the same)

Comment: I will but before that could you please tell me if you are in any way affiliated with the Wubi project? (contributor,maintainer etc?)

Comment: There is no wubi project or specific maintainer. Wubi is maintained by the Ubuntu installer team. Anyone is free to contribute; only they can modify it. What does that have to do with your answer?